# What does "Help and Company" exactly mean?

Tags: idioms

I have just watched a movie named "The Equalizer 2". There is a scene when the main character asked an old friend's wife to lift him to a station and then she said "Help and Company". What does it exactly mean?

The scene is at 2:43 and here is the link, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BgZFaMJRxM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He will provide help with the kids and company during the drive.

Comment: May I ask, Is it a catchphrase that commonly used? such as if my parent is not at home and my friend wants to come to my house, then I can say 'Help and Company' while I am cleaning the toilet.

Comment: It's not a catchphrase. It's just what she said.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Davo 